# Spring: bean injection in Configuration within library

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have an spring boot project with kotlin that is used as a library. 
In its @Configuration class I create a spring bean by using method with @Bean annotation:

```
@Bean(name = arrayOf("someConfig"))
fun someConfig(@Value("\${someconfig.val1}") val1: String, @Value("\${someconfig.val2}") val2: String, @Value("\${someconfig.val3}") val3: String): SomeConfig {
    return SomeConfig(val1, val2, val3)
}
```

It is worth pointing that SomeConfig is a class in yet another dependency I cannot modify and it needs the 3 params constructor.

Then I use the injected bean in some other component within the library:

```
@Component
class SomeComponent {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var someConfig: SomeConfig
    ...
}
```

I have some tests for this and they work fine.

The problem comes when I add the library as a dependency to other project and I want to use SomeComponent, I get the next error:

```
Field someConfig in com.test.services.SomeComponent required a bean of type 'com.other.project.SomeConfig' that could not be found.
```

So the question is: ¿Is it possible to do what I am trying? and if so, ¿What is the problem with the way I currently have?

Comment: Are you sure that your `@Configuration` file from the library is scanned by your Spring Boot application?

Comment: @Nikem I'm not sure how to verify that, but i do have the `@ComponentScan("com.test")` in the Application class.